# Group by month with date time in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, mysql-8.0

halo i want to count the data and group by month (month start date) then show in date time,  any idea ?

table_a

```
timestamp
2020-11-28 04:00:00
2020-11-28 05:00:00
2020-12-29 01:00:00
2020-12-29 02:00:00
2020-12-29 03:00:00
```

expected result:

```
timestamp             count
2020-11-01 00:00:00     2
2020-12-01 00:00:00     3
```

my query is:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-dd HH'), '%Y-%m-dd HH'), count(*) as count
from table_a
```

but my results was:

```
timestamp    count
2020-11-00     2
2020-12-00     3
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: i'm using mysql 8 @stickybit

Comment: Your query has no `GROUP BY` clause. It'll generate an error (or, if the server is badly configured another result) not the result you claim to get. There's also no zeroth day of the month. Are you sure you posted the right query and the right result?

Comment: how about to show the start date of every month ? @stickybit

Comment: That would be the first, if it's that you're asking.

Comment: but its not include time, i want to show in date time @stickybit

Comment: The first at 00:00:00.000000... then...

Comment: thanks for the respond, i have fixed the issue with add group by month(timestamp) ! @stickybit could you upvote my questions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year(timestamp), month(timestamp), 1)) as yyyymm,
       count(*)
from table_a
group by yyyymm;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the query look a like that my query too! i have fixed the issue with add group by month(timestamp) ! could you upvote my questions ?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the question with add `group by month(timestamp)` , i m ignored the minuted, the important things is group by month , here are my full query :

```
SELECT timestamp, count(*) as count
from table_a 
group by month(timestamp)
```

then the output show :

```
timestamp             count
2020-11-01 04:00:00     2
2020-12-01 01:00:00     3
```